# My teacher names hazard rates "probability". How can it be, since h(t) is unbounded as quotient?

Tags: survival, hazard

Hazard rate, depending on the time scale, can be 0.1 or 100 or 1000. It's just a ratio. So why do people call it a "conditional probability"? Will I fail an exam, if I say that?

So, is this that "for some time granularity" (time unit) the hazard rate will behave as a probability (bounded by 1), but for others - just as rate (unbounded)?

I was told, that it depends on whether it's about discrete (where it's always <=1) or continuous time, but I don't understand it yet.

On this page: http://onbiostatistics.blogspot.com/2015/06/some-explanations-about-survival.html

> "Hazard Rate is the probability of an event occurring given that it
> hasn’t occurred up to the current point in time. Hazard rate is the
> instantaneous risk of a patient experiencing a particular event at
> each specified time. The instantaneous rate with which an event occurs
> at a single point in time. It is the probability that the event occurs
> between time t and time t+delta given that it has not yet occurred by
> time t, divided by delta, as delta becomes vanishingly small. Note
> that rates, unlike probabilities, can exceed 1.0 because they are
> quotients."

For me, the hazard rate, as a derivative, is like an instantaneous velocity - a potential to do something. I can drive a car faster or slower. If I drive fast all the time, I will reach the destination sooner. That's all. It's what happens "NOW" (at some small dt). People may die faster or slower at a given moment (dt->0), which, integrated, makes the survival probability.

But how come the hazard rate itself is a probability? I can see this quite often in textbooks!
In place it's called probability, while a few words later - that it is NOT! I'm totally lost.

Comment: For both your questions--what justifies calling this a "probability" and will you fail an exam--you need to ask your teacher rather than us.  We cannot possibly know what your teacher thinks or intends.

Comment: Probabilities must be in [0,1].  Something that is not cannot be a probability.  So a hazard function on a continuous distribution cannot represent probabilities.  But a hazard function on a discrete distribution **is** a conditional probability, since the discrete hazard function is $\Pr(Y = y | Y \geq y)$ and will be nonzero.

Comment: Thank you, Professor Harrell. So, since in a typical survival analysis operates on a continuous time (days can be expressed hours, hours in seconds, in milliseconds, and so on), saying that "Hazard Rate is the probability of an event occurring given that it hasn’t occurred up to the current point in time" is overall not valid, right? I saw recently hazard rates as high as 2.5, and cumulative hazard 1.5-2.5. So while it's a measure of "intensity of occurrence of events" at given time (it may rise of drop later), it's not just a probability, even is many source named it so. Is this correct?